# Linux command is not working under cmd

Tags: python

Can you please let me know what is wrong with my below code :

```
def ume():
    cmd = None
    p = r'/myfolder/xyz'
    cmd = ["who am i | awk '{print $1}'", "date"]
    fh = open(p, 'ab+')
    try:
       b = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=fh)
       b.wait()
       fh.flush()
    finally:
       fh.close()

ume()
```

its not appending `date` output in `xyz` file. Just giving the output of this command :

> (who am i | awk '{print $1}'

I want both command's o/p should write in single line with one space like below.

**mmd Tue Apr 19 13:25:35 UTC 2016**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code if the default shell is bash:

```
def ume():
    cmd = None
    p = r'temp.txt'
    cmd = ["export wai=`whoami | awk '{print $1}'`;" "export dt=`date`;" "echo $wai $dt"]
    fh = open(p, 'ab+')
    try:
       b = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, universal_newlines=True, stdout=fh)
       b.wait()
       fh.flush()
    finally:
       fh.close()
ume()
```

Comment: Awesome.. Thanks a lot. You are a genius.